# Rails 3 - rmagick - Windows - problem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rmagick

I have:
Windows XP Professional SP3
Ruby 1.8.7
Rails 3.0.3
ImageMagick 6.5.6 Q8
Rmagick 2.12.9

I try to use rmagick functionality in my Rails application...

When I try to use rmagick in **Ruby** application, everything working fine!

but when I try to use rmagick in **Rails** application, there is message:
***no such file to load -- RMagick***

in controller I have:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'RMagick'
```

in gemfile:

```
gem 'rmagick-2.12.0-x86-mswin32', '2.12.0', :path => 'vendor'
```

Help me, please!

Comment: My Gemfile has `gem 'rmagick', :require => 'RMagick'` so maybe try that one. What happens if you remove both of the `require`s from your controller? Sorry but I can't think of anything else right now.

Comment: I'm sorry to bother you
but no result
here screenshot http://base.ukrpatent.org/result.jpg

Comment: How about `gem 'rmagick', '2.12.0', :require => 'RMagick'`? If that doesn't do it then hopefully someone with more Windows experience then me will come along soon.

Comment: Thanks very much for help but don't work ))
ok, I will be thinking...

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me on a **Windows Vista**, **Rails 3.1**, **Ruby 1.9.1** environment:

Try to download RMagick from https://github.com/rmagick/rmagick/zipball/master

then extract it in *'C:\RailsInstaller\Ruby1.9.2\lib\ruby\gems\1.9.1\bundler\gems\rmagick-rmagick'* (fix it to fit your needs).

And then call 'gem install rmagick'

It worked fine for me, now when I need to use rmagick in a Rails App I just add to the Gemfile:

```
gem "rmagick"
```

and than call 'bundle install'.

Good luck.

PS: please note that I installed Rails with http://www.railsinstaller.org tool.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to use **rails 3.2.12** and **ruby 2.0.0p0 (2013-02-24) [i386-mingw32]** which is the latest version as of this writing.

Try the following steps I made when I successfully installed rmagick in my local machine:

1. Download **ImageMagick-6.8.3-7-Q16-x86-dll**.
2. Install the file in the local machine.
3. Copy the imagemagick from program files directory where it is usually installed to the same directory where the ruby directory is located.
4. Open a command line. Type "**C:\www\Ruby>gem install rmagick -- --with-opt-dir=C:\www\ImageMagick**" and press **Enter**.

I hope this helps to solve your problem too.